# Problems with versions greater than WP 6.0.3 and the get_user_meta() function

Tags: php, wordpress

On upgrading from v6.0.3 to v6.1.1 or lately the v6.2.2, the function get_user_meta() (used in my theme) is not working correctly!

In the following code v6.1.1 or v6.2.2 returns $guid as an empty value, however when I revert back to v6.0.3 all works as expected and $guid is correct (obviously for the same $memberCode)!

In both cases, $user is returned correctly.

```
$user = get_user_by( ‘login’, $memberCode );

if($user != false){

//Get the guid of this user
$guid = get_user_meta($user->ID, ‘guid’, true);
```

Any pointers to what the problem could be or how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: use user_login
$user = get_user_by( 'user_login', $memberCode );